# Dynamically arrange controls to be tiled within a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have an 3D image shown in a control to which i can do several things (rotate, zoom, draw stuff, etc...).  This control is Dock filled into a panel and toolbars allow us to control the image operations.

I'd like to be able to view several images at the same time by tiling the images dynamically.  So :

- If the user opens 1 image, it takes up 100% of the space
- If the user selects 2 images, they are shown side by side
- If the user selects 4
  images, they are tiled.
- etc...

Basically, this could easily be achieved with a MDI form but this module is nested into a application so that is not possible.  I *could* do this all manually, by calculating size and using TableLayoutPanel but i figure there must be something out there that does the trick.

Any suggestions?

*Note: i am in winform and i do have DevExpress 11*

Answer (score 1):

If you just need Tiling, `TableLayoutPanel` can totally do that for you:

```
    private void btnNewImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (imgCount == 0)
            tlp.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Image " + ++imgCount, Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, 0, 0);
        else
        {
            // tlp is the TableLayoutPanel which is docked as Dock.Fill
            if (tlp.RowCount == tlp.ColumnCount)
            {
                tlp.ColumnCount++;
                for (int i = 0; i < tlp.RowCount; i++)
                    tlp.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Image " + ++imgCount, Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, tlp.ColumnCount - 1, i);
                tlp.ColumnStyles.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < tlp.ColumnCount; i++)
                    tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, (float)100.0 / (float)tlp.ColumnCount));
            }
            else
            {
                tlp.RowCount++;
                for (int i = 0; i < tlp.ColumnCount; i++)
                    tlp.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Image " + ++imgCount, Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, i, tlp.RowCount - 1);
                tlp.RowStyles.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < tlp.RowCount; i++)
                    tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, (float)100.0 / (float)tlp.RowCount));
            }
        }
```

You can replace `new Button` with your control name, I used button as an example control.
This code assumes by hitting add new button, a row or a column should be added to the layout. you can customize it to do whatever you want.

Hope this helps.